# Why does my CMD print [?] when I execute my C code for this particular exercise?

Tags: c

I am learning C from K&R Programming Book and alot of my code is fine for most of the exercises. Except for this particular exercise when I execute it via CMD on Windows 10, and after I input characters and press enter, the result is a box with a 0101 in it. [?].

Exercise 1-9

Example: After executing code, I will enter "hello " as input in the cmd line and once I press enter, the result is then .

I appreciate all answers, thank you very much.

Edit:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

main(void)
{
int c;

while((c = getchar() != EOF)) {
    if (c == ' ') /* find a blank */
    {
        putchar(' '); /* print the first blank */
        while((c = getchar()) == ' ')
            ;
    }
    if (c != EOF) /*print normal character */
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Also some information: using GCC and notepad++

Comment: Where's the code? The result is what?

Comment: Looks like you copied a bunch of characters with incorrect encoding into your question; they don't render properly. I guess Windows encoding is not the same as UTF(-8).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry guys and girls, just updated with code and exercise number.

Comment: I still want to see what the result is. Your post just says "the result is ."

Comment: @Evert I am not sure what you mean. I actually typed it all out using notepad++, and all my other code and exercises have compiled correctly and displayed correctly except when I started to do the ' ' blank exercises.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka just updated. For some reason when I copy and pasted the code from CMD to here, it won't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is this line:

```
while((c = getchar() != EOF)) {
```

It should be:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
```

With your version, you actually assign the value of `getchar() != EOF` to `c`. This will usually be `1`, unless `EOF` is reached in which case it'll be `0`.

Comment: Ahhh okay this makes sense. This was explained in the book, I see though I have to group it correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's an [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) problem.

The expression `c = getchar() != EOF` is equal to `c = (getchar() != EOF)`. I.e. you assign the result of `getchar() != EOF` to the variable `c`. After this `c` will be either `1` or `0`.

You need to think about those extra parenthesis you have, and where to put them.

Comment: Ahhh okay this makes sense. This was explained in the book, I see though I have to group it correctly. Thank you.